# Firebase database Assign a certain user id when user opens app

Tags: android, firebase

I would like to assign a certain unique id for each user, without registering or loging in when they open my app. That unique id should be different for every phone that uses the app. I would like to store data for each user in a database as they use the app overtime, and that data should be a child of the unique id. I am using android studio java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for Firebase's anonymous authentication, which assigns a unique ID to the user on the device without requiring them to provide any credentials. In is simplest form this looks like:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously()
```

For the complete documentation, see [Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).